# Private Case Comments in Salesforce Lightning Service Cloud

Tags: lightning, servicecloud, internal-comments

It appears that case comments are deprecated in the Lightning version of Service Cloud Cases, in favor of using a chatter feed. As far as I can tell, if a user has access to a case, they have access to the feed. We would like a private channel for our support techs to discuss the details of a case that is hidden from users. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Continuing this thought... I've heard about orgs creating a "private post" checkbox for chatter posts that can restrict access to the post to certain types of users (perhaps by Public Group or Profile). Is anyone familiar with this approach?